# how to put all folders that do not have 'AAA' or 'BBB' in name into a zip file ? linux

Tags: linux, zip, tar

In the current folder I have lots of subfolders and they have files in them. How can I put those folders with no `AAA` or `BBB` in the name into a .zip file?

```
123AAAcc
  123.txt
  BBB.csv
222BBBss
  ...
ADFAAA
  BBB
    adsf.txt
vvBB
  111.mov
  BBB.avi
```

I've tried the following and it also excludes `vvBB\BBB.avi` and `ADFAAA\BBB\*`. I would like to keep those.

```
tar -zcvf test.tgz --exclude='*AAA*' --exclude='*BBB*' .
```

The problem is, how can I have `--exclude` only work on level 1 subfolder names, but recursively on all filenames and folder names?

Hopefully I have a .zip file containing:

```
vvBB
  111.mov
  BBB.avi
```

I would like to achieve this as one command line. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this behavior by chaining together the following commands:

`ls` will list all of the files and folders in the current directory.

`grep -v "\(.*BBB.*\)\|\(.*AAA.*\)"` looks for all names with AAA or BBB (surrounded by anything), then (with `-v`) excludes them and returns all other results.

`xargs tar -cvzf test.tgz` will take arguments from a pipe and apply them to `tar`. All together, you get:

```
ls | grep -v "\(.*BBB.*\)\|\(.*AAA.*\)" | xargs tar -cvzf test.tgz
```

The partial results I get are:

```
$ ls
123AAAcc
222BBBss
ADFAAA
vvBB
$ ls | grep -v "\(.*BBB.*\)\|\(.*AAA.*\)"
vvBB
$ ls | grep -v "\(.*BBB.*\)\|\(.*AAA.*\)" | xargs tar -cvzf test.tgz
a vvBB
a vvBB/111.mov
a vvBB/BBB.avi
```